# How to pass a value of an input field to component only when its valid?

Tags: angular

I have an input field for postalcode.

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="formField">
     <mat-label>Postalcode</mat-label>
     <input #postal formControlName="postal" matInput type="text"  (change)="onPostalInput(postal.value)">
    </mat-form-field>
```

After I leave this postalcode field, its validated by my code in .ts Component

```
postal: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^[0-9]{5}$")),
```

and the value is passed to component with

```
onPostalInput(postal.value)
```

What I want to achieve is, that this call "onPostalInput(postal.value)" is done only when the postalcode is valid. At the moment it is executed independend of validation.

How I can do that?

Comment: You've skipped over some code that might help. My guess... You just need to check `valid` on the FormControl. Since you assign to an object named `postal`, I would guess you want something like `if (postal.valid) { onPostalInput(postal.value); }` ?

Comment: use <input #postal formControlName="postal" matInput type="text"  (focusout)="onPostalInput(postal.value)">

Comment: @daddygames so, I need to check it on my typescript code instead  of angular html?

Comment: You can do it in the change event HTML also if you prefer. `(change)="postal.valid ? onPostalInput(postal.value) : null)"` or something like that.